# Center image vertically html

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div class="store_module" id="@store.ID" style="
    margin-left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-color: #343233;
    cursor: pointer
  ">
<div class="store_image" style="
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px
">
<img src="@store.ImageLogo" style="
  display: block; 
  margin: auto;
"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Why can't I center the logo picture vertically? It must be very easy, but I really can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give its parent `display: table;` and the image `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`:

```
.store_image {
    display: table;
}
.store_image img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

By the way, there are plenty of sites, even questions on SO, describing this problem. ([Proof](https://www.google.nl/search?q=css+vertically+center+image&aq=1&oq=css+vertically+center+i&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j60l2.9718j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

EDIT:

According to [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/) you can leave out the `display:` rules.